# About viewmodels inside models and nested binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently developing applications using WPF. I have two question about MVVM rules.

1. Can models have viewmodels as a property? Let me give an example, i have a model named Receiver and a viewmodel named ModeSelectionViewModel. I am initializing them inside the mainviewmodel. Receiver model has a public property of type ModeSelectionViewModel, which is initialized as follows inside the mainviewmodel:

```
Receiver = new SerialReceiver();
ModeSelectionViewModel = new ModeSelectionViewModel();
Receiver.modeSelectionViewModel = ModeSelectionViewModel;
```

I wonder if this breaks any MVVM rule or is it something to be avoided.

2. My second question is about binding. In the view, binding to nested properties can be done but i wonder if it is a good approach or should i find another way to implement the viewmodels so that i wouldnt need binding to nested properties? As an example:

```
{Binding ModeSelectionViewModel.ConfigViewModel.GPIO.State}
```

which is Viewmodel->Viewmodel->Model->Property)

Comment: That is the wrong way round. View models may have properties of model types, but a model does not know a view model, so it can not have a property of a view model type. For the other question, nested properties in Binding Paths are of course ok.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I would suggest you present viewmodels to views rather than models. Copy data from model to viewmodel to bind. Copy viewmodel to model to commit changes.